# How to typeset a backslash and get line breaks in URLs?

Tags: symbols, line-breaking, urls

I have a lot of Windows file/folder paths and register paths in my document. And I'm having 2 problems:

1. The `\` is seen as and escape character which obviously doesn't compile. `\\` Starts a new line rather than escaping the `\`. I tried `$$` too, but that didn't work either.
2. There is no line breaking, so the paths go out of the page margin.

At the first question, is there a quick way to solve this rather then changing all `\` to `/` ?

At the second question, I tried `\path{}` from the `url` package but that didn't help.

Comment: Maybe the [`menukeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) package provides what you need

Comment: Please augment your question with some actual code, to make it easier to diagnose and (hopefully) fix the issue raised by your comment that trying "`\path{}` from the `url` pacakge ... didn't help". Without more having something specific to work with, it may be difficult to suggest a fix.

Comment: Regarding your first question, you can typeset a backslash using `\textbackslash`.

Comment: What do you want do do with these paths? If you want do typeset them in a LaTeX document I also would recommend you `menukeys` with its `\directory` command.

Comment: @Jubobs Could you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You're correct. The backslash is TeX's (default) escape character; it signals to TeX that what follows is different from "normal text". Therefore, simply typing `\` will not produce a backslash in the output. (Incidentally, if you type `\` followed by any amount of blank space, you will only produce a so-called *control space*, not a backslash.)

   To typeset a backslash in text mode, use 
   `\textbackslash`; in math mode, use `\backslash`.

   Now, if you find (as I do) that typing `\textbackslash` every single time is a pain in the neck, you can always define a macro with a shorter name that does exactly the same thing, like so:

   ```
   \newcommand\bs\textbackslash
   ```

   and then use that macro throughout your file instead of `\textbackslash`.

   One more thing: what should you do to produce the following output?

   > C:\My documents

   You can try

   ```
   C:\textbackslashMy documents
   ```

   but that's not going to work, because TeX is going to interpret `\textbackslashMy` as a macro, won't find it defined anywhere, and will hurl abuse at you. To obtain the desired output, either insert either a blank space or an empty group (`{}`) right after `\textbackslash`, like so

   ```
   C:\textbackslash{}My documents
   ```
2. The `url` package makes your life easier in that respect. Load it in our preamble and then use the `\url` command to typeset a URL; the package will take care of the line breaking for you. Note that you don't need to use `\textbackslash` inside `\url{...}`, because `\url` already "detokenizes" its argument. Happy days!

Here is some code illustrating those two points:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\bs\textbackslash % shorthand for \textbackslash

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\noindent
A backslash in text mode: \bs \\
A backslash in math mode: $\backslash$\\[2em]
A long URL: \url{C:\Program Files\Steam\Jubobsgame\procrastinators__paradise\level_one\five_years_into_the_PhD}
\end{document}
```

and here is the corresponding output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I find that many answers in this forum apply only to LaTeX and not necessarily plain TeX. We use plain TeX, so the answers sometimes simply don't work.

But, I found a solution for displaying TeX's special characters that work for us, so I thought I'd share it. I have no idea if it will work for LaTeX, though it seems like it should.

You can include a character by using `\char` followed by the character's ASCII code in decimal. We enclose that in `{` and `}`, though I'm not sure it's needed unless the following text is another digit. So, e.g., to display a backslash, use `{\char92}`, for a left brace use `{\char123}`, etc. Hope this helps someone.